# Добавить placeholder в input

Tags: html, css, angular4

У меня есть пользовательский ввод. Ярлык находится на входе и после щелчка по метке выходит поверх ввода.
     Я хочу, чтобы заполнитель стал видимым, а ярлык - вверху ввода, когда будет нажата кнопка ввода.

Comment: На русском stackoverflow принято задавать вопросы только на русском языке, пожалуйста переведите.

Answer (score 0):

`JavaScript` можно не использовать, если не надо сохранять состояние элемента:

```js
//при изменении input описание фиксируется вверху или опускается вниз если поле пустое
$('input[type="text"]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() != '') {
    $(this).parent().find('span').addClass('active');
  } else {
    $(this).parent().find('span').removeClass('active');
  }
})
```

```css
label {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

input {
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: all .3s;
}

input:focus+span,
input:hover+span,
span:hover,
span.active {
  bottom: 105%;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="inp">
 <input type="text" id="inp">
 <span>Введите текст</span>
</label>
```

Пример на [Codepen](https://codepen.io/MaxManchak/pen/rKrKqv?editors=0110).